# wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: java, jvm, 32bit-64bit

I'm getting this error pointing to some .so file when running my application on a Solaris machine. However, the application runs just fine in my Windows machine. If I'm not mistaken, my application is expecting for the 64-bit version but I only have a 32-bit version of the .so file in the Solaris machine. Is there a way I can fix this so it will use the 32-bit version instead? I understand it has nothing to do with the bytecodes but probably with the JVM. I tried running using -d32 or -d64 but it has no effect.

UPDATE:

This is the exact error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: librvjs11.so: ld.so.1: java: fatal: librvjs11.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32<br>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)<br>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)<br>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)<br>
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)<br>
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)<br>
```

I've already updated LD_LIBRARY_PATH so it includes the directory containing the file above.

Comment: "I'm getting this error"... What error are you speaking of? Posting the error reported will help people understand what you are referring to.

Comment: @Vineet: jasonline means a "wrong ELF class" error. If you've ever seen one, it doesn't carry much information -- just the filename. It does indeed mean that the app is trying to use a 32-bit binary in a 64 bit environment.

Comment: @trutheality, I know what it corresponds to. The important thing however is that it can be reported in the context of an UnsatisfiedLinkError. Therefore, without knowing the failure involved, and the files in question, it is going to be very difficult to aid in troubleshooting. I would have suggesting looking at the contents of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but that would be presumptuous.

Comment: @rutheality, you're welcome. For now, your answer might help the OP perform some basic troubleshooting, but unless it is known what library failed to load, I'm afraid there is very little psychic debugging that one can do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [the conversation in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172105/wrong-elf-class-elfclass32/6172255#6172255), it was inferred that the JVM was a 64-bit process. This was confirmed using the `pflags` command in Solaris.

Apparently the `-d32` flag passed to the JVM was being ignored. This was due to the possibility of the JVM being a 64-bit one, which was incapable of operating in the 32-bit mode. The resolution might therefore be to install a 32-bit version of JVM, and use the same.

Answer (score 3):

What I think is happening is that your app is using a library that has its own pre-compiled binaries, and those are 32 bit.

Your options are either to get a 64 bit version of the binaries, or force java to run in 32 bit which is what `-d32` is supposed to do.
However, can the jvm on that machine run in 32 bit? If it can't then the `-d32` will cause java to spit out a warning that it can't run in 32 bit and that it will continue in 64 bit.
Are you getting that warning?

I'ma CW this since Vineet is doing all the helping.

Comment: I tried using the option -d32 on the Solaris machine but it doesn't have any effect and still shows the same error.

Comment: @jasonline, you might want to check if the -d32 flag has been conveyed correctly to the JVM; probably using /usr/ucb/ps -auxww. Additionally, you might also want to check if 32-bit and 64-bit libraries are being mixed. It is weird if both -d32 and -d64 flags report the same results.

Comment: @vineet: Right, I used /usr/ucb/ps to see if the -d32 appears but I actually don't see it. Any idea why?

Comment: @jasonline, are you using a script that starts the JVM? If so, you might want to debug that script. However, I wouldn't be too concerned with this finding for I expect the JVM to operate in 32-bit mode by default.

Comment: Correct, even if I don't specify -d32, it should've run as a 32-bit application but I'm confused because it gave me the above error. I thought if your application is running as 32-bit, it will find also 32-bit libraries.

Comment: @jasonline, I think it would then help to check if the JVM is a 32-bit JVM or not. I expect the JVM on the recent versions of Solaris to support both 32-bit and 64-bit modes without requiring a separate 64-bit Java home. What does `java -version -d32` report, and how different is the output from `java -version -d64`?

Comment: @vineet: both outputs are the same and JVM is a 64-bit: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_01-b06) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.6.0_01-b06, mixed mode)

Comment: @jasonline, err, did you just state that -d32 also reports that the JVM is 64-bit. If so, that is your problem. You might want to investigate how to get the 32-bit version, and the [information posted here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_layering) might not apply to your platform. I'm referring to this to be specific - "Since Solaris has both a 32 and 64-bit J2SE implementation contained within the same installation of Java, you can specify either version.  If neither -d32 nor -d64 is specified, the default is to run in a 32-bit environment."

Comment: @vineet: yes, are you saying the outputs of "java -version -d32" and "java -version -d64" should be different? I get a feeling that Java only executed "java -version" part and disregarded "-d32" or "-d64". I tried supplying some other values like "java -version -d100" but it also returned the same output.

Comment: @jasonline, yes, I would expect the versions to be different; only the 64-bit version of the JVM should report the 64-bit flag. Unfortunately, I remember the behavior on Linux and Windows (where the outputs are different) and not of Solaris, so I cannot confirm it. But your application's behavior suggests that I might be true. It might be attempting to load 32-bit libraries in a 64-bit process, which is illegal.

Comment: @vineet: "... attempting to load 32-bit libraries in a 64-bit process" - yes I think this is what's happening. In Windows, I still get the same output like: Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @jasonline, yes that's what I meant, the string in Windows for 32-bit JVMs does not convey the architecture, while the 64-bit versions do. The JVM of Solaris might not have the same behavior, given the manner in which it is installed for the newer versions, and that's why I cannot vouch for the same behavior.

Comment: @vineet: Weird. My Windows XP is 32-bit. Why does my application act like as if it is a 64-bit process? Do you know why JVM is not accepting the -d32/d64 option? It doesn't display when shown in /usr/ucb/ps

Comment: @jasonline: how, specifically, are you running your application?

Comment: @jasonline, I'm not sure why `ps` is not reporting the flags. There is another test however to verify if the process is a 32-bit or a 64-bit one. Use `pflags <pid>` where pid is that of JVM. A 32-bit process uses a ILP32 data model, while a 64-bit uses a LP64 one. This is more accurate in your case, for it reports the data from the underlying process. You'll need to ensure that the JVM is not spawning off new processes using `ProcessBuilder` or related Java classes.

Comment: @trutheality: I'm running from a script: java <followed by options, etc>.

Comment: @jasonline, do you continue to see LP64 when you pass the -d32 flag? If so, there are some possibilities - 1. there is a bug in JVM. 2. the script is not passing the -d32 flag. 3. the JVM installed is strictly a 64-bit version, and will not operate in a 32-bit mode.

Comment: @vineet: Yes, I see LP64 even if -d32 flag is passed. I think I see the possible problem. java is pointing to a sun4u64.sunos.5.8. I guess I need to change this to point to the non-64-bit version so it can run as a 32-bit application. Feel free to post an answer so I can choose it.

Comment: @jasonline, I think you should attempt installing the most recent version of the JVM, and use that for your application. That should ideally ensure that all the three points are covered, for the newer version will (and is known to) accept the -d32 flag, and also operate in 32-bit mode by default, assuming that there are no bugs.