# Downgrade java application to 32-bit

Tags: java, jvm, solaris, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

When I run my Java application on a Solaris machine, I'm having issues with a shared library since it is in 32-bit format. How do I make my application run as in 32-bit format so it would be consistent with the shared library? I compile my application in Windows by the way, and I believe it has nothing to do with the bytecodes.

Comment: it will b helpful if you put error message here

Comment: Actually, it is from this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172105/wrong-elf-class-elfclass32

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. Does this answer your query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783662/java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility

Comment: @Joachim: I've actually checked that but couldn't find anything useful. I don't have any issue with the bytecodes - as according to that post, it's not implementation-dependent. So, what I want is to run the bytecode so it uses 32-bit libraries because those are the only ones available.

Comment: @jsaonline: in that case simply start your app with a 32bit JVM.

Comment: @Joachim: Are you saying that I should download 32-bit JRE and use that to run my application?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, he's using Solaris. The Java home should support 32-bit operation by default, unlike separate 32-bit and 64-bit packages for Linux and Windows. Of course, my memory only goes as far as recent versions of Solaris, so you might be right for the older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "-d32" flag can help?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html

Comment: The question is a near-duplicate of a previous question - in fact he OP mentioned there, `-d32` didn't have any positive effect.

Comment: This question does not mention that, and -d32 is _the_ way to indicate the 32/64-bitness of the JVM which is what was asked.  This may in turn indicate that the diagnosis is wrong.

Comment: It actually didn't do any help, and I don't know why. I tried seeing the process info using ps to see the parameters but '-d32' or '-d64' disappeared.

Comment: @Thorbjørn - sorry, could have been more accurate with my comment ;) There's a discussion in the comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172105/wrong-elf-class-elfclass32/6172255#6172255).

Comment: @Jason, print out system properties after launch. This Will allow you to deduce the details of the underlying JVM.

Comment: @Thorbjorn: yes, I can see it is running as a 64-bit application, even if -d32 is passed, and I don't see the parameter in /usr/ucb/ps.

Comment: @Jason, is the 32-bit JVM even installed?  Consider recompiling your shared library for the 64-bit architecture...

Comment: @Thorbjorn: Yes, I just found out there's a 32-bit version installed but the current java binary is pointing to the 64-bit versino. I think that's why the -d32 was ignored. Yes, but I don't have the liberty of recompiling the shared library for 64-bit.