# Linux Lubuntu Eclipse Checkstyle SWT Error

Tags: linux, eclipse, swt

I have Lubuntu 12.10 64bit installed and Eclipse Juno Distribution. If I switch to Preferences- Checkstsyle and there on configure (to open a checkstyle config) I get the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/home/user/Development/Tools/firefox18.0.2'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/user/Development/IDE/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/626/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4234.so: libxpcom.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4234.so: libxpcom.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
    Can't load library: /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so
)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1970)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationConfigureDialog.createDialogArea(CheckConfigurationConfigureDialog.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationConfigureDialog.create(CheckConfigurationConfigureDialog.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor.configureCheckConfig(CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor.java:505)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor.access$6(CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor.java:492)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor$PageController.widgetSelected(CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/user/Development/IDE/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/626/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4234.so: libxpcom.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4234.so: libxpcom.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
    Can't load library: /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1955)
    ... 50 more
```

I have found lots of threads about this problem in the net but none could help me. What exactly do I have to do? Currently I have only set the MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME path in my .profile in home/user.

I have currently installed Oracle JDK 1.7 which I referred in PATH and JAVA_HOME.

Would appreciate it to get some help of you guys.

Greets
Marc

Comment: Doesn't this help? [wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172105/wrong-elf-class-elfclass32)

Comment: @Baz is right, you need to have valid libraries for your platform. Your libraries are  built on 32bit pltaform but you need 64 bit (you need to install 64bit version or recompile them)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar problem on my Fedora 19 (64-Bit). I resolved it by the following steps:

```
1. $ sudo yum install libwebkitgtk*
2. Restart Eclipse
```