# Installing Levenstein Functions on centos 6 cloud server

Tags: mysql, centos, user-defined-functions

I'd like to install the following UDF's from [sam J levy's site](http://samjlevy.com/2011/03/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/)

I have run through the windows (32 bit) installation with wamp for my testing server with no problem. Now I have my proper server running centOs 6.4. I have copied the .so files to

> usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/damlev.so

I then try to run one of the sql statements to create the function

> CREATE FUNCTION damlev RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'damlev.so';

And get the following error

> 1126 - Can't open shared library 'damlev.so' (errno: 22 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/damlev.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)

What Am I doing wrong. Is it because the server is 64bit?

Edit Bounty Started:

If more details about the server are required I can gladly supply them. I need this function installed.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested resolutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172105/wrong-elf-class-elfclass32#6173613)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to use the `damlev.so` library included in the [damlev.zip](http://samjlevy.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/damlev.zip) file of the [Levi's site](http://samjlevy.com/2011/03/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/), but that library is for an Ubuntu 32-bit system, therefore it cannot work on your Centos 64-bit system, so you'll have to compile from sources.
As a prerequisite, you must install the `g++` compiler and the mysql development libraries:

```
yum install gcc-c++ mysql-devel
```

Also, if you don't have `wget` and `unzip`, install them with the following command:

```
yum install wget unzip
```

Then download the source code and unzip it somewhere:

```
cd tmp
mkdir damlev
cd damlev
wget http://samjlevy.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/damlev.zip
unzip damlev.zip
cd src
```

Finally compile, install the plugin and restart the mysql server:

```
g++ -fPIC -I /usr/include/mysql/ -o damlev.so -shared damlev.cpp
cp damlev.so /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/
service mysql restart
```

Please note that all the above command must be run as "root".

Comment: Hi Enzino. Just to confirm, these are all comands that I run putty or other ssh client?

Comment: Ok I think I have g++ compiler installed. Where do I get the development library's from. I have download a rpm file from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mysql-devel and copied it to /usr/bin but I keep getting No packege available returned. Is this the right library and the right folder to put in?

Comment: Ok I'm now stuck. I believe I have g++ installed along with mysql-devel. When I run this  gcc -I/usr/include/mysql -o damlev.so -shared -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient damlev.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNSStFY.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not b                         e used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/ccNSStFY.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Hi Mark. First of all, apologies for my late response, but only now I've read your comments. You should simply recompile with the `-fPIC` option. See the updated answer for the complete command.

Comment: Hi Enzino. That seems to have sorted, no errors in ssh but now when I try run the sql to create the function I get this error: `Can't open shared library 'damlev.so' (errno: 22 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/damlev.so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0)`

Comment: It turns out this worked. I recompiled using the folling code `g++ -fPIC -I /usr/include/mysql/ -o damlev.so -shared damlev.cpp`
`cp damlev.so /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/`
`service mysql restart` then I ran the sql and it worked. I'll edit the answer and accept it. Thankls for all the help